# Remove router function in python

Tags: python, api, networking, routes

Hi just wondering if anyone can tell me why this code isn't working
It's giving an internal server error
Thanks

```
@app.post("/removerouter/")
def removerouter(name: str):
    Graph.remove_node(name)
    return "success"
```

And this is the function inside Graph

```
class Graph:
    def __init__(self):
        self.nodes = []
        self.edges = []
    def remove_node(self, name):
        self.nodes.remove(name)
        for Edges in self.edges:
            if name in Edges:
                self.edges.remove(Edges)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the code that you posted, I would say that the issue is somehow related to how you remove your edge(s) in the `for` loop.

When you delete a list element using the `remove()`function in Python, it changes the remaining element's indexing.
For more details and alternatives, see this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1207406/4862968).

I also don't understand why you are using an iterator variable called `Edges` in your for loop. Python variables shall always start with a lowercase letter in order not to clash with any existing (or future) class name.

I would rather do something like this:

```
class Graph:
    def __init__(self):
        self.nodes = []
        self.edges = []

    def remove_node(self, name):
        self.nodes.remove(name)
        self.edges = [edge for edge in self.edges if name not in edge]
```

Note that I'm using a list comprehension here to assign a new list to `self.edges`.

If you want to avoid list comprehension, you could also keep your `for` loop and first store the indexes of the edges that need to be removed. Then, for each index, you can simply do `del self.edges[index]`.